# How to login to a Oracle database using sqlite3 in python

Tags: python

I want to run sql queries by logging in to the remote server. I'm trying to use sqlite3 in python:

///

```
import sqlite3


sql_connect = sqlite3.connect('dwhdb')
cursor = sql_connect.cursor()

query = "SELECT typename, timelevel, status, datatime FROM log_loadstatus WHERE typename like 'DC_E_CPP%' and DATEDIFF(day, log_loadstatus.datatime, GETDATE()) = 0;"

results = cursor.execute(query).fetchall()

print results

sql_connect.commit()

sql_connect.close()
```

///

Here my db name is dwhdb. But when I run the script, it throws an error that the table can't be found.

The strange thing is this table exists and if I check it by directly doing ssh to the server and run: iqisql -Udc -P12@SHr00t -Sdwhdb  -w2000
And when I run queries it shows the data from the table.

I believe while using sqlite3 there's no username and password passed. Is it due to that? If yes, how can I connect to the db using username and password?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use sqlite3 to connect to Oracle. To connect to Oracle, you can use cx_Oracle package.

Check cx_Oracle package documentation - https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html

Comment: Can I connect to MySql db using this?

Comment: For every Database System, we have specified packages for the same. Like for mysql, we have a Python Package - mysql

Comment: Checkout this link - https://realpython.com/python-sql-libraries/ for the list of Python Libraries to connect to Database.

Comment: ok.. Thanks @Anurag! Sorry for the ignorance I want to use sqlite3 for  Sqlite server itself. But is there any way to put username and password while establishing connection.